# JavaFX line chart throwing cast exception

Tags: java, exception, javafx, charts

I'm trying to put another chart in my window and I'm getting cast exception. I got one barchart that is working, but when I`'m clicking button to add data to linechart it's throwing an exception.
Here is the code:

```
@FXML
private BarChart<String, Double> barChart;
@FXML
private CategoryAxis xAxis;
@FXML
private NumberAxis yAxis;
@FXML
private LineChart<Double, Double> lineChart;
@FXML
private CategoryAxis linexAxis;
@FXML
private NumberAxis lineyAxis;

public void createChart(ActionEvent event) {} //this method creates and populates barChart

public void loadLineChart(ActionEvent event) {

    linexAxis.setLabel("Wind speed [m/s]");
    lineyAxis.setLabel("Probability [%]");

    ObservableList<XYChart.Series<Double, Double>> lineChartData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    LineChart.Series<Double, Double> series1 = new LineChart.Series<Double, Double>();
    series1.setName("Series 1");
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<Double, Double>(0.0, 1.0));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<Double, Double>(1.2, 1.4));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<Double, Double>(2.2, 1.9));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<Double, Double>(2.7, 2.3));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<Double, Double>(2.9, 0.5));

    lineChartData.add(series1);

    lineChart.setData(lineChartData);

    lineChart.getData().add(series1);
}
```

Here is stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Double cannot be cast to java.lang.String
at javafx.scene.chart.CategoryAxis.calculateRequiredSize(CategoryAxis.java:382)
at javafx.scene.chart.CategoryAxis.autoRange(CategoryAxis.java:363)
at javafx.scene.chart.Axis.computePrefHeight(Axis.java:577)
at javafx.scene.Parent.prefHeight(Parent.java:935)
at javafx.scene.layout.Region.prefHeight(Region.java:1435)
at javafx.scene.chart.XYChart.layoutChartChildren(XYChart.java:687)
at javafx.scene.chart.Chart$1.layoutChildren(Chart.java:94)
at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1087)
at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1093)
at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1093)
at javafx.scene.Scene.doLayoutPass(Scene.java:552)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePulseListener.pulse(Scene.java:2397)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.lambda$runPulse$29(Toolkit.java:398)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.runPulse(Toolkit.java:397)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.firePulse(Toolkit.java:424)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:518)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:498)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulseFromQueue(QuantumToolkit.java:491)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.lambda$runToolkit$403(QuantumToolkit.java:319)
at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$null$48(GtkApplication.java:139)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I need this feature, because I'm trying to stack two charts on each other. Barchart with histogram and linechart on it. The data, that I'm trying to populate line chart with is not final data. I got an list that is hold data that I would like to present on line chart.

Edit.
Here is fxml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?import javafx.scene.chart.BarChart?>
<?import javafx.scene.chart.CategoryAxis?>
<?import javafx.scene.chart.LineChart?>
<?import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
```

```
    <BarChart fx:id="barChart" alternativeColumnFillVisible="true" layoutX="31.0" layoutY="64.0" prefHeight="502.0" prefWidth="767.0">
        <xAxis>
            <CategoryAxis side="BOTTOM" fx:id="xAxis" />
        </xAxis>
        <yAxis>
            <NumberAxis fx:id="yAxis" side="LEFT" />
        </yAxis>
    </BarChart>
    <Button layoutX="420.0" layoutY="17.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#loadLineChart" text="Load chart" />
    <Button layoutX="24.0" layoutY="17.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#createChart" text="LOAD" />

  <LineChart fx:id="lineChart" layoutX="52.0" layoutY="571.0" prefHeight="334.0" prefWidth="500.0">
    <xAxis>
      <CategoryAxis fx:id="linexAxis" side="BOTTOM" />
    </xAxis>
    <yAxis>
      <NumberAxis fx:id="lineyAxis" side="LEFT" />
    </yAxis>
  </LineChart>
</children>
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem (snippets are not enough)

Comment: From the exception, it looks like you need to cast xValues to String.

Comment: or You can change your `CategoryAxis linexAxis;` to `NumberAxis linexAxis;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either need to change your x-Values to Strings.

```
series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<Double, Double>(Double.toString(0.0), 1.0));
//Do the rest of the x-values here!
```

or replace

```
CategoryAxis linexAxis;
```

with

```
NumberAxis linexAxis;
```